# Clicking on a tab of tab control, I want to do an action in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, tabcontrol

When I click on a tab, so it shows the content of that tab page but I want to do an action when the tab is selected, for example when I click on "*finance tab*" there would be a combobox in the Finance Tab, that combobox should fill with the data from sql server, is it possible ?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [TabControl.SelectedIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selectedindexchanged.aspx) Event

```
Private Sub TabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) _ 
     Handles TabControl1.SelectedIndexChanged

'suppose your *finance tab* instance is TabPageFinance 
If TabControl1.selectedtab is tabPageFinance
  'do stuff
End if

'or suppose *finance tab* index is 0 
If TabControl1.selectedindex = 0
  'do stuff
End if

End Sub
```

Comment: @Chris why in my case I can't use `selectedTab`? is it not available in Compact Framework?

Comment: @ImmerAllein I can't find an official documentation but yes, some threads seem confirm that `SelectedTab` property is not available in Compact Framework. `SelectedIndex` would be the only way to get or set the selected tab.

Comment: @Chris Agree. I ended up using `TabControl1.SelectedIndex`. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible !!

You can use panel with combobox in it

About how to fill combobox fill with your data you can see this link

http://vb.net-informations.com/dataset/bind-combobox.htm

Comment: Thanx for the reply, I didn't mean "How to populate a combobox from Database" I meant that by clicking a tab I want to do an action like filling data from database into combobox.

Comment: @user2202527 .. your combobox is usually prepared in design time and in runtime you just fill it with your data .. and each tabcontrol index changed then your tabpage will change by itself ..